# Why is on.exit not allowed in examples on CRAN?

Tags: r, r-package, cran

I submitted a package to CRAN with the following setup code for a temp file, within an example in the documentation:

```
#'   conn <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), tmp <- tempfile())
#'   on.exit(DBI::dbDisconnect(conn), add=TRUE)
#'   on.exit(file.remove(tmp), add=TRUE)
```

I received the form letter back:

```
Please make sure that you do not change the user's options, par or
working directory. If you really have to do so within functions, please
ensure with an *immediate* call of on.exit() that the settings are reset
when the function is exited. e.g.:
...
old <- options()         # code line i
on.exit(options(old))      # code line i+1
...
options(digits = 3)
...
If you're not familiar with the function, please check ?on.exit. This
function makes it possible to restore options before exiting a function
even if the function breaks. Therefore it needs to be called immediately
after the option change within a function.

Please always make sure to reset to user's options(), working directory
or par() after you changed it in examples and vignettes and demos.
e.g.:
old <- options(digits = 3)
...
options(old)
```

However, if I set a breakpoint using `debug(file.remove)` and run it with `example(myfun)` I can clearly see the temporary file get deleted appropriately.

What is the rationale behind this request?

Comment: In the example are you calling `on.exit` inside a function? `on.exit` should not be called at the top level because there is nothing to exit from in that case.

Comment: Some help page that use `on.exit` in their examples: `?par`, `?make.socket`, `?source`, `?palette`. Note they are all used inside functions.

Comment: It is not inside a function, it is directly in the example. on.exit definitely gets triggered when I run the example, I can see it delete the file.

Comment: The behavior should be the same if you run `example()` or you copy/paste the code into your terminal.  If you were to copy/paste `tmp <- tempfile();on.exit(file.remove(tmp), add=TRUE)` in your terminal the file would still be there because there's nothing to trigger the `on.exit`